# Calculating lengths and percentages of potholes with SQL query in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, sql, length

I have a shapefile in QGIS that holds information about the amount and severity of potholes on a road network across several cities:

- The road network is split into segments of different lengths (meters)
- Each segment is split into 10m parts
- Each part has potholes measured in percentage of 10 meters (zero, mild, important and severe potholes)
- Each city has several segments of the road network (city zip code)

I would like to have for each city the percentages of pothole types compared to the total length of the city segments. Is possible to do this in one SQL query?

[image: attribute table]

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate ? :)

Comment: I'm sorry the "Each part has potholes measures in lengths (zero, mild, important and severe potholes)' is wrong.
The correct phrase is : "Each part has potholes measures in percentage of 10 meters)". I guess this chages the query a bit, sorry.

Comment: Not much - just use `SUM(<pothole_measure> * 10)` if those are fractions (0.0 - 1.0), or `SUM(<pothole_measure> * 0.1)` if they are percentages (0 - 100).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Total length of city segments :

```sql
SELECT
  pt.zip,
  SUM(pt.segment_length) AS total_segment_length
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT
  "CITY ZIP CODE" AS zip,
  "SEGMENT ID" AS segment_id,
  "SEGMENT LENGTH" AS segment_length
FROM potholes_table
) pt
GROUP BY pt.zip
;
```

- Potholes types :

```sql
SELECT
  "CITY ZIP CODE" AS zip,
  SUM("MILD POTHOLES" * 10) AS mild,
  SUM("IMPORTANT POTHOLES" * 10) AS important,
  SUM("SEVERE POTHOLES" * 10) AS severe
FROM potholes_table
GROUP BY "CITY ZIP CODE"
```

- Combine the two :

```sql
WITH total_length AS (
  SELECT
    pt.zip,
    SUM(pt.segment_length) AS total_segment_length
  FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    "CITY ZIP CODE" AS zip,
    "SEGMENT ID" AS segment_id,
    "SEGMENT LENGTH" AS segment_length
  FROM potholes_table
  ) pt
  GROUP BY pt.zip
),
types_length AS (
  SELECT
    "CITY ZIP CODE" AS zip,
    SUM("MILD POTHOLES" * 10) AS mild,
    SUM("IMPORTANT POTHOLES" * 10) AS important,
    SUM("SEVERE POTHOLES" * 10) AS severe
  FROM potholes_table
  GROUP BY "CITY ZIP CODE"
)
SELECT
  tot.zip,
  tot.total_segment_length,
  typ.mild / tot.total_segment_length * 100 AS mild_perc,
  typ.important / tot.total_segment_length * 100 AS important_perc,
  typ.severe / tot.total_segment_length * 100 AS severe_perc
FROM
  total_length tot
  INNER JOIN types_length typ ON tot.zip = typ.zip
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'll try this right away.

Comment: If I get your query right, you sum the segment lengths. But it mustn't. You will see the total segmeent length several times (for each "part" of a segement). But the value of each segement length is unique. Not sure if I am clear ?

For example :
SEG000001  40
SEG000001  40
SEG000001  40
SEG000001  40
etc... 

The total length of SEG000001 is only 40 meters

I am also struggling to format correctly this query in qgis db manager, but i guess i will manage.

Comment: You don't get the query right, I put a sub-query with `DISTINCT` to get the segment length only once.

Comment: WITH total_length AS (
  SELECT
    pt.zip,
    SUM(pt.segment_length) AS total_segment_length
  (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    "CITY ZIP CODE" AS zip,

Isn't there a FROM before (SELECT DISTINCT ?

Comment: little oversight !

Comment: Ok, it worked, thanks once again.  I would like however to understand how 'tot' and 'typ' are declared. Are they sql builtin commands ?

Comment: It's a table alias `FROM table_name AS alias_name`, the `AS` is optional. So, `total_length tot` is the same as `total_length AS tot`.

Comment: Ok, now I Got it.

Comment: Before computing the percentages, I have to filter by the type of road (let's say we have a column "belongs_to" with the values 'Interstate', 'State' and 'County'. And I would like to compute the potholes % still by zip code but only for the 'County' roads.
My guess is to insert [WHERE BELONGS_TO = 'County'] inside the total_length AS ( and the inside the [types_length AS ( ]. Am I right ?

Comment: @dot314: exactly !

Answer (score 4):

If by "*each city*" you refer to *each distinct value* in `"CITY ZIP CODE"`, the query would simply be:

```
SELECT
  "CITY ZIP CODE",
  SUM("MILD POTHOLES") / (COUNT(*) * 10) AS mp_pct,
  SUM("IMPORTANT POTHOLES") / (COUNT(*) * 10) AS ip_pct,
  SUM("SEVERE POTHOLES") / (COUNT(*) * 10) AS sp_pct
FROM
  <potholes>
GROUP BY
  1
;
```

---

**Note:**

This assumes that each *part* is exactly 10m in length - we simply count the *parts* per ZIP code and multiply by 10. If that is not the case (I mean, how could it, really, IRL - but that's what your question says), go with @J.Monticolo's answer *if* the values in `"SEGMENT LENGTH"` are aware of any length remainder, or work with `ST_Length` of the actual geometries instead.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear but actually each segment has a different length, but they are all split into eaqual parts of 10 meters. For example, if a segement is 150m long, it will be split into 15 10m parts. And each part has potholes measures in it.

Comment: Sure, and this query works under that assumption. Just saying that, IRL, roads tend to not have a total length evenly dividable by 10...anyways, I updated the wording from *segments* to *parts*.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't mentioned it, but the last part of each segement is the remainder, so it can be less than 10m.

Comment: Well, on second look on your table it seems it won't matter at all; as long as you do not use the `ST_Length` calculated from the actual geometries, both answers here use the lengths given as attributes - and both columns seem to have values dividable by 10.